# mysql | specific request

Tags: mysql, database, request, substring

I have mysql column:

```
[{"name":"Color","value":"Red (+5$)","price":"+5"}] // options column
```

And request:

```
SELECT C.options, C.qty, P.PRICE
FROM `cart` C
LEFT JOIN `products` P ON C.productid = P.id
WHERE C.userid = '3c9494e7ff22e2a7ac01a3e95fbbc0e4'
```

But I need this:

```
SELECT C.options, C.qty, (P.PRICE + (substract price +5 from options column))*C.qty
FROM `cart` C
LEFT JOIN `products` P ON C.productid = P.id
WHERE C.userid = '3c9494e7ff22e2a7ac01a3e95fbbc0e4'
```

Is it possible to get the request above? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why? Why parsing or do something with JSON in DBMS? If that's intention of your app - then store data in separate column(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to summarise the values

Give this a try

```
SELECT C.options, C.qty, SUM(P.PRICE + c.options) * C.qty
FROM `cart` C
LEFT JOIN `products` P ON C.productid = P.id
WHERE C.userid = '3c9494e7ff22e2a7ac01a3e95fbbc0e4'
GROUP BY c.options,c.qty
```

If you need to convert the options column, do like this

```
SELECT C.options, C.qty, SUM(P.PRICE + CAST(c.options AS DECIMAL)) * C.qty
FROM `cart` C
LEFT JOIN `products` P ON C.productid = P.id
WHERE C.userid = '3c9494e7ff22e2a7ac01a3e95fbbc0e4'
GROUP BY c.options,c.qty
```

Comment: I can't use c.options as this is a string.

Comment: Ok! But is this the column you want to use here?